# TestNG: How to set SoftAssert as not Failured

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'd like to use TestnNG's SoftAssert type of assertion for getting some warnings.

After test, in results are values eg:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Can I get the result for failed SoftAssert as Errors or Skipped tests? Of course, I'd like to have Failures for failed HardAsserts (regular Asserts), too.
So, after change the report for 1 HardAssert and 1 SoftAssert will have something like this:

```
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

or

```
        Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

Comment: Can you please share your code /

Comment: Please refer this https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/soft-assert/

Comment: @ Ankur Singh  What part of code will help you to solve this problem? This problem isn't for small part of code, but wide.
@JeffC Ok  next time, I'll show, what I was read before.

Comment: I see, that surefire could return Errors and not return Failures:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829845/maven-surefire-return-code-is-0-on-failed-tests so I'll study, what condition should have test, to return this.

Answer (score 0):

After "sleeping with the problem" and JeffC's comment, thanks again :), i found answer for my question.
For Surefire plugin I could set configuration parameter skipAfterFailureCount to 1.
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skip-after-failure.html  for specify tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can add assert message to figure out which soft assert is failed like this:

```
softAssert.asserEquals(actual, expected, "Your customized message")
```