# How can I set Maven TestNG project return code according to failed tests?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

My selenium test suit is managed by Maven and TestNG.
All works perfect, in case of particular tests failure I have perfect reports created with Extent Reports.
The problem is that Maven return code is always 0, both if all the tests passed and if several tests failed while we need to have indication for tests failures in Maven return code.
So far I couldn't find how can I do that.
My `pom.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
<!--                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>-->
                        <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suite}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Test suites are like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite" thread-count="1" parallel="methods">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utilities.ExtentListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="Chrome Sanity Tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name = "Sanity">
                </include>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="MainRunner">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829845/maven-surefire-return-code-is-0-on-failed-tests

Comment: @itronic1990 Thanks a lot, but I already saw that post before asking this my question. Possibly I do not understand something, but I can't see there what I'm looking for

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal What will this give me?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `<configuration>` Try to add

`<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>`

inside maven-surefire-plugin.

Set this to "true" to ignore a failure during testing. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, but quite convenient on occasion.
Default value is: false.
User property is: maven.test.failure.ignore.

**Maven command to execute: mvn clean compile test**

**Complete Code:**

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I will try this and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, please let me know.

Comment: I didn't forgot, don't worry. Just have some more urgent problems to solve. Also I need devOps assistance to validate this while he is busy these days too. I hope to test this this week. Anyway, your upvote is already here :)

Comment: I still didn't try. To do this I have to collaborate with our devOps team, but they are highly busy these days. We have some big and critical project to do these days. But I didn't forget about this issue, believe me. As soon as I will try I will update you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks bro 

Comment: Well, I talked with our devOps team leader. The problem was with their settings, so now it works correct without any implementation / changes from my side. So actually I can't check if your solution correct. But I really appreciate your help. Will give you some additional upvote :)